# Check if value is negative and apply CSS in React JS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am working on a ReactJS website where I pull prices from API using Axios. Now that I did it successfully I am looking for a way to show if 24 hour change percentage is positive it would have a green color if its negative red. My class looks like this.

```
class BtcTicker extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{fix_value(this.props.data.lastPrice, 2)} USDT</p>
        <p>{fix_value(this.props.data.priceChangePercent, 2)}%</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: add your json response code , and fix_value function code

Comment: something like this should work: <div style={{color: this.props.data.priceChangePercent > 0 ? "green" : "red"}}>

Comment: function fix_value(text,to) {return (text/100*100).toFixed(to).toString()}

Comment: wow it worked thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have to show the "percentage" value in color.Then try edit your code like following:

```
class BtcTicker extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{fix_value(this.props.data.lastPrice, 2)} USDT</p>
        <p style={{color: Math.sign(this.props.data.priceChangePercent) === -1 ? "red" : "green";}}>{fix_value(this.props.data.priceChangePercent, 2)}%</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: <div style={{color: this.props.data.priceChangePercent > 0 ? "green" : "red"}}> this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Here's the simplest example using an inline `style` prop:

```
<p style={{
  color: someNumber < 0 ? "red" : "green"
}}>
  {someNumber}
</p>
```

There are "better" ways depending on your situation, e.g. using class names, Styled Components, etc. - but that depends on your environment and what libraries / frameworks you are using.

Comment: <div style={{color: this.props.data.priceChangePercent > 0 ? "green" : "red"}}> this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [Math.sign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign) method to check if the number is a negative or positive, then use the return value in an if statement that implements conditional rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using inline style you can define css class and use it using 
`<p className={condition ? 'red' : 'green'}>Value</p>`